# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Indices' because it is not a delegate type in elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

I am a beginner in Elasticsearch. While doing a sample application it shows an error in `d.AllIndices()` says that

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Indices' because it is not a delegate type

Code:

```
ElasticClient c = new ElasticClient();
c.DeleteIndex(d => d.AllIndices(true));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var c = new ElasticClient();
c.DeleteIndex(new DeleteIndexRequest(Indices.AllIndices));
```